# Convergent condition in the definition of free profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

I have a (perhaps simple) question about free pro-$C$ constructions.

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a set. The free pro-$C$ group over $X$ is a pro-$C$ group $F$ together a $1$-convergent map $f: X \to F$ satisfying the universal property: whenever $g: X \to G$ is a $1$-convergent map to a pro-$C$ group, there is a unique $1$-convergent map $\varphi: F \to G$ such that $\varphi f = g$.

This is the definition of Wilson's book. Assuming this definition?

> *Why is the $1$-convergent condition essential?*

Ribes-Zalesskii makes slightly different: the natural generalization of free group to profinite case when we want to define a free pro-$C$ group on a profinite space $X$ (or pointed profinite space) not asks for convergent condition, it needs $F = \overline{\langle f(X) \rangle}$. For any set $X$, take the one-point compactification $X \cup \{\ast\}$ and so this definition works for $(X \cup \{\ast\},\ast)$. We have the $1$-convergent map
$$X \hookrightarrow X \cup \{\ast\} \to F(X \cup \{\ast\},\ast)$$
The free pro-$C$ group on $X$ is actually the free pro-$C$ group on $(X \cup \{\ast\},\ast)$. So

> *it seems to me that this condition essentially is another way to asks for density*.

In the proof of $F$ is the inverse limit of free pro-$C$ groups on finite subsets of $X$ (Proposition 3.3.12 of Ribes-Zalesskii book's) it seems that this condition is necessary, but how can I know that there is no another way to prove it? I know that the examples in free pro-$C$ constructions are not friendly at most, but is there some example where it fails if the convergent condition is not given?

Comment: If you take the free pro-$C$ group on a set $X$ without the $1$-convergent condition, then this is the same thing as the free pro-$C$ group on the profinite space which is the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$, which is not even metrizable.  So the convergent condition lets you get down to a much smaller profinite group.  This is because a map from $X$ into a profinite group is the same thing as a map from $\beta X$ into a profinite group by the universal property of $\beta X$.

Comment: Notice when you want to force the $1$-convergent property you construct $F$ as the inverse limit of the system of free pro-$C$ groups on the finite subsets of $X$ so that if $Y\supseteq Y'$, then the map from $F_Y\to F_{Y'}$ sends $Y\setminus Y'$ to $1$.

Comment: Ribes and Zalesski do make lots of use of free profinite groups on a set X converging to 1. It turns out to play better the role of the free profinite group on X then if you used the version of the definition without 1-convergence because, for example, the free profinite group on countably many generators converging to 1 embeds in the free profinite group on 2 generators but this is not true if you do not impose the convergence to 1 condition

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I see. Thank you for the clear explanation (as usual :))!

Comment: You are welcome.  I found this convergence to 1 strange at first as well but eventually got the point. Of course I used to have an office down the hall from Ribes so that might have helped.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Nice. I suppose this was quite helpful ;)